# Bitrix init.php

Tags: php, битрикс

Создаю файл init.php в битриксе, когда он пустой - все отлично , сайт работает, но когда я пишу даже минимальный код в нем , допустим

```
<?php 
require_once("psss.php");
?>
```

То сайт сразу ложится, ничего не работает, при загрузке абсолютно любой страницы домена показывает много знаков вопроса и ссылку на документацию битрикса по .settings.php

Как можно это решить?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `?>` в конце

Comment: Попробуйте, для начала, заменить
require_once("psss.php");
на
include_once("psss.php");

Comment: А вообще, советую настроить на сайте логирование ошибок в файл (используя /bitrix/.settings.php), и в случае белого экрана там будет доступен текст ошибки - станет ясно в чем проблема и что делать.

Comment: скорее всего ошибка в файле psss.php. Включите вывод ошибок в .settings.php параметр debug надо сделать true. Минимальный код это если бы echo 1; написали для проверки.

Answer (score 0):

Убрать в конце скрипта `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Включи вывод ошибок в файле .settings.php
2. То что сайт ложиться, уже хорошо, значит init.php вызывается в прологе и при включенном выводе ошибок у тебя на страницах покажет на какой строке была ошибка и в какой файле
   (будет показывать тебе путь к init.php и какая строка ему не понравилась)
   эту строку исправляешь или комментишь) После исправления всех ошибок все заработает